# Trouble passing an ID between controllers in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, controller, routes

I have a web app that has three models - Customers, Jobs and Rooms.

The three models are associated as follows:

```
class Customer < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :jobs
end

class Job < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :customer
  has_many   :rooms
end

class Room < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :job
end
```

My issue is as follows:

- After saving a new room, I want to redirect to the path that corresponds to the job which would be something like /customer/1/jobs/3.
- The customer id is not passing through into parameters from the new action for Rooms.

Here are my new and create actions from the Rooms controller:

```
def new
  @customer = Customer.find(params[:customer_id])
  @job = Job.find(params[:job_id])
  @room = @job.rooms.build
end

def create
  @customer = Customer.find(params[:customer_id])
  @job = Job.find(params[:job_id])
  @room = @job.rooms.build(room_params)

  respond_to do |format|
    if @room.save
      format.html { redirect_to job_path(@job), notice: 'Room was successfully created.' }
      format.json { render action: 'show', status: :created, location: @room }
    else
      format.html { render action: 'new' }
      format.json { render json: @room.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
    end
  end
end
```

I get the following error:

```
Couldn't find Customer without an ID
```

And in the parameters I'm seeing the following:

```
{"job_id"=>"3", "format"=>"1"}
```

I am confused by what is happening here - does anyone know how I would get the customer id to pass from the job view, to the room save and then use that customer id to redirect to the appropriate path?

I'm sorry if this is convoluted, I struggled with how to ask this for a couple of hours.  Please ask for clarification if you need some.

---

Routes.rb file:

```
resources :customers do
  resources :jobs
end

resources :jobs do
  resources :rooms
end

devise_for :users

devise_scope :user do
  root :to => "devise/sessions#new"
end
```

---

New Room Form:

```
<div class="panel panel-primary">
  <div class="panel-heading">
    <h3 class="panel-title center">Add New Room</h3>
  </div>
    <div class="panel-body">

        <%= simple_form_for([@job, @room], html: {class:'form-horizontal'}, wrapper: :horizontal_form) do |f| %>
          <div class="form-inputs">
            <div class="col-md-12">
                <h3 class="bump-right-two"><u>Room Details</u></h3>
            </div>
            <%= f.input :room_type, collection: ["Kitchen", "Bathroom", "Closet", "Island", "Bar", "Furniture", "Laundry Room", "Office", "Miscellaneous", "Custom Order"], prompt: "Select Room Type" %>
            <%= f.input :material, collection: ["Maple", "Cherry", "Oak", "Hickory", "Walnut", "Bamboo", "Thermowrap", "Melamine", "Olon", "Custom Material"], prompt: "Select Material Type" %>
            <%= f.input :material_details %>
            <%= f.input :exterior_colour %>
            <%= f.input :interior_colour, collection: ["White", "Classic Maple", "Dark Truffle", "Caramel", "Stained", "Pre-finished Plywood"], prompt: "Select Interior Colour" %>
            <%= f.input :panel_back_style, collection: ["Veneer", "Door Style", "Melamine"], prompt: "Select Panel Back Style" %>
            <%= f.input :finished_ends, collection: ["Veneer", "Door Style", "Melamine"], prompt: "Select Finished End Material" %>

            <div class="col-md-12">
                <hr class="style-one" />
                <h3 class="bump-right-two"><u>Door Style Details</u></h3>
            </div>

                <%= f.input :upper_door_style %>
                <%= f.input :lower_door_style %>
                <%= f.input :drawer_front_style %>

            <div class="col-md-12">
                <hr class="style-one" />
                <h3 class="bump-right-two"><u>Drawer Box Details</u></h3>
            </div>

            <%= f.input :drawer_box_style, collection: ["Dovetail", "Melamine", "Hettich"], prompt: "Choose Drawer Box Style" %>
            <%= f.input :track_style, collection: ["Tandem", "Hettich", "Accuride"], prompt: "Choose Track Style" %>

            <div class="col-md-12">
                <hr class="style-one" />
                <h3 class="bump-right-two"><u>Counter Top Details</u></h3>
            </div>              

            <%= f.input :counter_top_material, collection: ["Granite", "Quartz", "Corian", "Laminate", "Marble", "Other"], prompt: "Select Counter Top Material" %>
            <%= f.input :counter_top_supplier, collection: ["Rosehill", "Floform", "Granite Mountain"], prompt: "Select Counter Top Supplier" %>
            <%= f.input :counter_top_colour %>
            <%= f.input :counter_top_edge %>
            <%= f.input :backsplash, collection: ["Yes", "No"], prompt: "Select Backsplash" %>
            <%= f.input :sink_install, collection: ["Yes", "No"], prompt: "Select Sink Install" %>

            <div class="col-md-12">
                <hr class="style-one" />
                <h3 class="bump-right-two"><u>Molding Details</u></h3>
            </div>

            <%= f.input :closed_to_ceiling, collection: ["Yes", "No"], prompt: "Select Closed to Ceiling" %>
            <%= f.input :crown_molding %>
            <%= f.input :under_cabinet_molding %>

            <div class="col-md-12">
                <hr class="style-one" />
                <h3 class="bump-right-two"><u>Custom Order Details</u></h3>
            </div>

            <%= f.input :order_name %>
            <%= f.input :order_description %>
          </div>

          <div class="form-actions">
            <%= f.button :submit, "Create New Room", class: "col-md-3 bump-right-two" %>
          </div>
        <% end %>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Can you post your `routes.rb`? And when does this error exactly occur?

Comment: @fivedigit The error occurs after clicking submit to save the new Room.  So it's basically hitting the Room Controller Create action and failing.

Comment: You need to post your form code from the `new` view.

Comment: @mccannf Do you want to see the new Room form, or the page that contains the button to create a new room?

Comment: The former - the new Room form.

Comment: @mccannf added...Do I need to add the customer's instance variable to the form_for tag?

Comment: You shouldn't need to. But I'm wondering why the new action does work, but the create doesn't. In either case, since a `Job` belongs to a `Customer`, you should be able to simply do `@customer = @job.customer` in `RoomsController`.

Comment: @fivedigit I may have typed incorrectly - it is failing at the New action and not making it to the create action.

Comment: Well that clears up the confusion then ;) I hope my answer works for you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`rooms` is a resource nested inside `jobs`:

```
resources :jobs do
  resources :rooms
end
```

So when you navigate to `RoomsController#new`, you have a `job_id` parameter, as `rooms` is nested inside `jobs`. But there is no `customer_id` parameter in the route since `customers` isn't part of the nesting. As `params[:customer_id]` is `nil`, you're getting the error.

Since a `Job` belongs to a `Customer`, you can simply fetch the customer through the job in the controller:

```
def new
  @job      = Job.find(params[:job_id])
  @customer = @job.customer
  @room     = @job.rooms.build
end
```